# Steampunk novel incorporating genetically engineered animals as vehicles

Tags: story-identification, steampunk, novel

I'm trying to find the name of a novel about a young prince/duke (pretty sure he was some young member of royalty) that gets kidnapped at night, put into a steampunk mecha, and taken into a different country (this was somewhere in Austria or Germany). He then meets a girl from Britain who is in the navy.

His country uses steampunk, mechanical weapons and vehicles, while her country uses genetically engineered animals.  For Example, their airships/blimps are actually whales that have been engineered and merged with other animals to produce hydrogen and other gases/functions.

Does anyone know this title?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Was it Scott Westerfeld's [Leviathan](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1416971734)?

From the intro to the article on the novel on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leviathan_(Westerfeld_novel)):

> Leviathan is a 2009 dystopian novel written by Scott Westerfeld and illustrated by Keith Thompson. First of a trilogy set in alternative version of World War I, it has Central Powers (known in-universe as "Clankers") using mechanized war machines opposed by Entente Powers (as "Darwinists") who fabricate living creatures genetically. The central protagonists are Aleksander, son of Archduke Franz Ferdinand; and Deryn, a Scottish girl with dreams of joining the British Air Service with her brother.